# C++ project compilation with Google Test working outside Conda environment but not inside - what could be the issue?

Tags: gcc, cmake, conda, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile a project that uses Google Test library inside a Conda environment. However, the build fails when run inside the Conda environment. Strangely enough, the build runs correctly outside the Conda environment.

I expect the project to compile and run correctly inside the Conda environment, just like it does outside the Conda environment.

The compiler used is the last version of MinGW (version 10.0.0 with GCC 12.2.0). It can be installed issuing

`conda install -c rnicolas mingw-w64-posix-ucrt`

Code is built using CMake, the CMake for this project is the following one (pretty similar to the one we can find in [GoogleTest Quickstart: Building with CMake](https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html)):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(embedded_cpputils)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP true)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/refs/tags/v1.13.0.zip
)

include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)


# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  mathTest
  test/mathTest.cpp
  src/math.cpp
  src/status.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
  mathTest
  GTest::gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(mathTest)
```

Finally, an example project to reproduce the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/rnicolas/example_gtest).

These are the steps I follow to build the project, in a terminal, inside the root folder of the project:

`mkdir build`

`cd build`

`cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

`cmake --build .`

The problem comes with the last line executed `cmake --build .`. When I am inside a conda environment, I get this output:

```
(mingw) C:\Users\MyUser\workspace\example_gtest\build> cmake --build .
[ 16%] Built target gtest
[ 33%] Built target gtest_main
[ 41%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mathTest.dir/src/math.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mathTest.dir/src/status.cpp.obj
[ 58%] Linking CXX executable mathTest.exe
CMake Error at C:/Users/MyUser/.conda/envs/mingw/Library/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:112 (message):
  Error running test executable.

    Path: 'C:/Users/MyUser/workspace/example_gtest/build/mathTest.exe'
    Result: Exit code 0xc0000139



    Output:


Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/MyUser/.conda/envs/mingw/Library/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:225 (gtest_discover_tests_impl)


mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\mathTest.dir\build.make:136: mathTest.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** Deleting file 'mathTest.exe'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:136: CMakeFiles/mathTest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:145: all] Error 2
```

But when I do the same outside the conda environment I get this other output:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\workspace\example_gtest\build> cmake --build . 
[ 16%] Built target gtest
[ 33%] Built target gtest_main
[ 41%] Linking CXX executable mathTest.exe
[ 66%] Built target mathTest
[ 75%] Building CXX object _deps/googletest-build/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock.dir/src/gmock-all.cc.obj
[ 83%] Linking CXX static library ..\..\..\lib\libgmock.a
[ 83%] Built target gmock
[ 91%] Building CXX object _deps/googletest-build/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/src/gmock_main.cc.obj
[100%] Linking CXX static library ..\..\..\lib\libgmock_main.a
[100%] Built target gmock_main
```

And this second output is what I was expecting to see when I run the project in a conda environment. Now I have a binary called mathTest.exe, that gives me the following output:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\workspace\example_gtest\build> mathTest.exe
Running main() from C:\Users\MyUser\workspace\example_gtest\build\_deps\googletest-src\googletest\src\gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 4 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 4 tests from MathTestGroup
[ RUN      ] MathTestGroup.BasicAssertions
[       OK ] MathTestGroup.BasicAssertions (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] MathTestGroup.muldivInt
[       OK ] MathTestGroup.muldivInt (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] MathTestGroup.muldivIntMore
[       OK ] MathTestGroup.muldivIntMore (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] MathTestGroup.muldivIntStatus
[       OK ] MathTestGroup.muldivIntStatus (0 ms)
[----------] 4 tests from MathTestGroup (7 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 4 tests from 1 test suite ran. (12 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 4 tests.
```

But if I activate again the conda environment and I try to run `mathTest.exe` I get nothing returned.

Comment: `Exit code 0xc0000139` means Windows failed to load one or more DLLs. Some of MinGW DLLs files are not found near the executable or in one of %PATH% directories.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing that came to my mind, but a conda environment only prepends more folders to the PATH. I could understand that behavior if the binary doesn't run outside conda, but it does. Right now it seems that some binary in the folders prepended by conda messes up the system.